# Checking for part of a key value pair

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently trying to develop an app that displays the parking tickets in NYC. The API I am using is https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/ati4-9cgt.json. I am trying to create a graph in which it shows how many tickets were distributed per month. There is a column called "issue_date", and it has year, month, followed by a bunch of numbers I am unsure of. Is it possible to only check the year and month part, instead of the whole value? For example, if I only want to see if the ticket was issued in January, I would check for 2017-01, but how would I make it so that the rest of the value doesn't get accounted and break the code? Thank you!

I forgot to include that I am a first year in college. I have limited knowledge on programming, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It's a timestamp. Just treat it as a timestamp with no useful time, e.g., a datestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can just grab the first 7 characters from the date.

Here is some code to count the number of entries per month and put that in an array:

```js
fetch("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/ati4-9cgt.json")
   .then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => {
        const byMonth = Object.entries(data.reduce( (acc, row) => {
            const month = row.issue_date.slice(0,7); // <--- just taking YYYY-MM
            acc[month] = acc[month] || 0;
            acc[month]++; // <--- counting
            return acc;
        }, {})).sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0])); // <--- sorting months
        console.log(byMonth); // <--- output [[month, count], [month, count], ...] 
    });
```

Comment: LOL whenever I see that `fetch(`  I always want to turn around to see if the dog is getting it...

Comment: Ah, perfect definition of asynchronous :)  the dog has  name now !

Comment: Is there any way you could dumb this down for a freshman in college? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Match issuedate with regexp, e.g. `/^2017-01/`

So if you have this whole array, you could:`onlyOnJanuary2017 = wholeArray.filter(object => object.issue_date.match(/^2017-01/));` as here: https://jsfiddle.net/twpq6nvd/

Additionaly, if you want to bucket themm try this

```
var result = arr.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  const date = new Date(item.issue_date)
  var key = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}`
  accumulator[key] = accumulator[key] || [];
  accumulator[key].push(item);
  return accumulator;
}, {})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d3qa96bg/1/

Comment: Just an FYI you can post the code in your fiddle right here (edit, then hit CTRL-M or click the "snippet" button and paste it right in.